# jQuery serialized data not being inserted into the database

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have three things going on.

I am sending information to jQuery using the following HTML form.

```
        <div id="note_add_container">
            <form id="note_add" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
                <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="location" />
                <button id="submit_note">Add note!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

This is the jQuery script that I am using to post such serialized information into the database.

```
   $('button').click(function () {  
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: $('#note_add').serialize(), 
            success: function(){
                  alert("Done"); 
            }
        });    
    });
```

This is the PHP that inserts the information into the database.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$location = $_POST['location'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO get (name, location)
VALUES ('$name', '$location')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

This does not work. I click the button and nothing happens. The alert does not fire. Can anyone lead me the right direction as to why my code is not working?

Comment: suggest to capitalize the ajax type to POST

Comment: @AhsanShah done and no luck still, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not work. I click the button and nothing happens. The alert
>   does not fire

Are you totally sure that click handler works? You must ensure that it works firstly, like,

```
   $('button').click(function () {  
      alert('It works');
   });
```

If it works, then you can move on. Otherwise check if its inside `DOMReady` `$(function(){ ...  })` and that `jquery.js` is loaded.

Assuming that it works,

How do you know what your PHP script returns? You simply assume that it "should work", here:

```
 success: function(){
  alert("Done"); 
 }
```

`success()` method actually holds a variable that is response that comes from the server side. It should be rewritten as,

```
 success: function(serverResponse){
  alert(serverResponse); 
 }
```

As for PHP script,

```
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

You only handling failure by 'echoing' error messages. You do not handle a situation when `mysqli_query()` returns `TRUE`. You should send something like `1` that indicates success.

And finally your code should look like this,

```
   $('#submit_note').click(function() {  
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: $('#note_add').serialize(), 
            success: function(serverResponse) {
                  if (serverResponse == "1") {
                    alert('Added. Thank you');
                  } else {
                     // A response wasn't "1", then its an error
                     alert('Server returned an error ' + serverResponse);
                  }
            }
        });    
    });
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO get (name, location)
VALUES ('$name', '$location')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die(mysqli_error($connection));
} else {
    die("1"); // That means success
}

/**
 * Was it $connection or $link?! Jeez, you were using both.
 * 
 */
```

Comment: Took me 2 years to mark this question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The callback function that you specified in your `$.ajax` call will only fire when a response is received from the server. Since you never send anything back to the client from the server after the data is inserted into the database, the client never calls `alert("Done");`. Add a line to your PHP file that sends a response to the client after a successful SQL insertion. The response can be as simple as a JSON object that says `{'status': 'success'}`.

Comment: Nothing is being inserted into the database, though. The jQuery serialized data not being inserted into the database.

Comment: The reason that nothing is being `alert`ed still stands. However, the problem of no data insertion is another one entirely. Can you inspect the values of `$name` and `$location` to make sure they're getting populated properly from the request?

Comment: Works like a charm when I take out the jQuery and add an action="" to the form provided.

Now about inspecting them, how can I do that? The webpage does not reload or return anything or takes me to the php file.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: so the problem wasn't that your data wasn't being inserted, it was that your `POST` request was never fired off at all. 

as for the webpage not responding after the request is fired, like I said, to get the javascript to call the callback function (such as `alert()`), you will need to send a response from the server to the client...

Comment: Why a response should be a `JSON` object? Why it can't be "1" (success) or "0" (failure)? If you're dealing with several values at once, then its okay to stick with JSON as you don't have better options.

Comment: @DaveJust certainly, you can do that. But if you want to output a specific error on the client side (e.g., 'unauthorized' or 'incorrectly formatted' or 'missing some fields', then JSON would make things easier. `{'status': 'fail', 'reason': ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a better way to handle your form. The serialize() helps, but it is better to work the data into a JSON string. When using JSO you will also need to set the dataType in the ajax call.

```
$('#note_add').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = $('#note_add').serializeArray();
    var formobject = {};

    $(formdata).each(function (event) {
        formobject[formdata[event].name] = formdata[event].value;
    });

    var data = {
        action: "formsend",
        json: JSON.stringify(formobject)
    };

    //* * send with ajax * *

    function sendajax(data) {
        var deferred = $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    sendajax(formdata).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.success == true) {
            alert("Done!");
        }
    })
});
```

**catch with PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'formsend') {

  $data = json_decode($_POST['json'];

// here you can now access the $data with the fieldnames

  $name = $data->name;
  $location = $data->location;

 // Write to the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO get (name, location) VALUES ('$name', '$location')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($link));
}

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0) {
    echo json_encode(array("success" = > true, "message" = > "data is submitted"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("success" = > false, "message" = > "an error occurred"));
}
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to know if `mysqli_query()` returns `true` or `false`. Its the single value. Why do you send several values?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following lines to your php file to send the response back:

```
HttpResponse::setCache(true);
HttpResponse::setContentType('text/html');       
HttpResponse::setData("<html>Success</html>");
HttpResponse::send();
flush();
```

change the ajax call as follows to see the result:

```
  $('#submit_note').click(function () {  
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: $('#note_add').serialize(), 
            success: function(respData) {
                  console.log('Response:', respData)
                  alert("Done"); 
            }
        });    
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="note_add_container">
  <form id="note_add" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="location" />
    <button id="submit_note">Add note!</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="response"> </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#submit_note").click(function() {
            var url = "post.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,
                   data: $("#note_add").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       $('#response').empty();
                       $('#response').append(data); // show response from the php script.
                   }
                 });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
   </script>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
// Insert here your connection path

<?php
if((isset($_REQUEST['name']) && trim($_REQUEST['name']) !='') && (isset($_REQUEST['location']) && trim($_REQUEST['location'])!=''))
{           
    $name = addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['name']));
    $location = addslashes(trim($_REQUEST['location']));    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO get (name, location) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$location."')";
    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    echo "1 record added";
}
?>
```